# What is the process to create a mirror-image of a JPG file without creating or using a decoder?

Tags: image, image-processing, jpeg

So, I'm kind of experimenting with image-manipulation at the byte-level (No 'Image' wrapper or libraries), so the language doesn't matter (I'm using C#) as much as the byte-manipulations, themselves.

I'm now trying to flip a a .jpg image (minus the magic number) over the x- and y-axis, but realized after some trial and error that I think the encoding is getting in the way. This is the code I'm using on a byte[] without the FF D8 or FFD9 includes:

```
    //No magic number included            
    public class MirrorImgOverXAndYAxes : IFunction
    {
        //No magic number included
        public byte[] Exec(byte[] jpgImage)
        {
            byte[] resultingImage = new byte[jpgImage.Length];

            for (var i = jpgImage.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                var indexToInsert = jpgImage.Length - 1 - i;
                resultingImage[indexToInsert] = jpgImage[i];
            }

            return resultingImage;
        }
    }
```

Right now, my assumption is that it's nowhere near as easy as this, and that I would have to build a full-blown decoder to be able to manipulate the image bytes like this.

Is it possible to create this mirror image without a decoder and would something like what I'm doing work?

Comment: No expert here. But without reversing the entropy-coding step, i don't see a possibility to do that as you won't know which byte is mapped to which pixel (not a 1:1 mapping; content-dependent). And that's probably only the start of problems (maybe also padding to get 8x8 macroblocks and so on)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi I guess just flipping a jpeg by switching the bytes position will not really work here, due to how jpg files are actually structured. if you want to learn more about that, you can look here [enter link description here](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-jpg-works-a4dbd2316f35)
But you could try to convert the image to a format that actually saves it's pixels within a single byte. For example bitmaps (.bmp).

Comment: Thanks, Huschdi. I think this question may not be valid since it's too broad of a question, but I'm going to go ahead and mark your answer for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: @Cygnus it's actually possible to manipulate a jpeg without completely decoding it, e.g. lossless rotate. But as stated in this answer it's not a simple matter of flipping the bytes.

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple way to do a mirror image that will work in general without decoding.

One problem is that JPEG images are encoded in MCUs that are in turn composed of blocks of eight by eight pixels. For simplicity assume the MCU is an 8x8 block the image width is 15 pixels. That means there will be a dummy column off the edge. If you just flip that, the dummy column will be visible and an image column will be off the edge.

Comment: It gets worse because of chroma subsampling. You generally want your image size to be a multiple of 16, not 8.